# how to solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on expo-navigation-bar

Tags: react-native, expo, store, playback

On firebase test I get this error when I use expo-navigation-bar in my project.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/WindowInsets$Type;
   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.vdiorio.EdhCounter, PID: 19866
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/WindowInsets$Type;
    at expo.modules.navigationbar.NavigationBarModule$getVisibilityAsync$1.invoke(NavigationBarModule.kt:115)
    at expo.modules.navigationbar.NavigationBarModule$getVisibilityAsync$1.invoke(NavigationBarModule.kt:20)
    at expo.modules.navigationbar.NavigationBarModule$safeRunOnUiThread$1.run(NavigationBarModule.kt:43)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.WindowInsets$Type" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
```